# Error extraño en float(string)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

estoy sacando unos datos de una API desde la que estoy reciviendo valores como cadenas, yo los parseo a float o int y los almaceno.

Tengo unos cuantos objetos que actualizar con esa API, y solo me da error en el último:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float:

He puesto varios prints para ver si devuelve algo raro, pero parece que no.

**Mi método**:

```
def actualice(self):
    coinmarketcap = Market()
    for coin in Coin.objects.all():
        print(coin)
        data = coinmarketcap.ticker(coin.cid, convert='EUR')
        print("\n\tprice: "+str(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['price']))
        coin.price = float(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['price'])
        print("\tmarket_cap: "+str(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['market_cap']))
        coin.market_cap = int(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['market_cap'])
        print("\tvolume: "+str(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['volume_24h']))
        coin.volume = int(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['volume_24h'])
        print("\tcirculating: "+str(data['data']['circulating_supply']))
        coin.circulating = int(data['data']['circulating_supply'])
        print("\tchange: "+str(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['percent_change_1h']))
        coin.change = float(data['data']['quotes']['EUR']['percent_change_1h'])
        coin.save()
        print("SAVED")
    return HttpResponse('OK')
```

Retorno de los **prints**:

```
Bitcoin

    price: 5444.1215436557
    market_cap: 93370288482.0
    volume: 2825283131.757767
    circulating: 17150662.0
    change: -0.21
```

SAVED

Ethereum

```
    price: 384.8865336125
    market_cap: 38761858187.0
    volume: 1162118039.2324457
    circulating: 100709832.0
    change: 0.03
```

SAVED

Litecoin

```
    price: 66.9622633446
    market_cap: 3844853190.0
    volume: 188237958.88713193
    circulating: 57418208.0
    change: -0.05
```

SAVED

Bitcoin Cash

```
    price: 618.4973716826
    market_cap: 10662268459.0
    volume: 271432967.2208214
    circulating: 17238988.0
    change: -0.09
```

SAVED

Bitcoin Gold

```
    price: 24.2842001795
    market_cap: 415855662.0
    volume: 9596136.587033633
    circulating: 17124536.0
    change: -0.62
```

SAVED

Zcash

```
    price: 152.0355570751
    market_cap: 662883581.0
    volume: 47968716.61182102
    circulating: 4360056.0
    change: -0.82
```

SAVED

Dash

```
    price: 197.7178511902
    market_cap: 1620546583.0
    volume: 117348604.64122398
    circulating: 8196258.0
    change: -0.08
```

SAVED

Status

```
    price: 0.0578630711
    market_cap: 200812850.0
    volume: 5929296.123765972
    circulating: 3470483788.0
    change: 0.01
```

Aquí en vez de devolver SAVED, me lanza el error.

No entiendo qué problema tiene con el **change** del coin **status**, tiene formato de float.

¿Alguna idea?

---**edito**---

Añado el error entero:

> Internal Server Error: /actualice/
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
>       response = get_response(request)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
>       response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
>       response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii\OneDrive\TFG\web\django\cryptoassistant\home\views.py", line 403, in actualice
>       coin.save()
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 729, in save
>       force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 759, in save_base
>       updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 823, in _save_table
>       forced_update)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 872, in _do_update
>       return filtered._update(values) > 0
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 709, in _update
>       return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1379, in execute_sql
>       cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1055, in execute_sql
>       sql, params = self.as_sql()
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1345, in as_sql
>       val = field.get_db_prep_save(val, connection=self.connection)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py", line 767, in get_db_prep_save
>       return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py", line 762, in get_db_prep_value
>       value = self.get_prep_value(value)
>
> File "C:\Users\etsii.virtualenvs\django-PSCmaJrS\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py", line 1754, in get_prep_value
>       return float(value)
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float:
>
> [15/Jul/2018 21:17:43] "GET /actualice/ HTTP/1.1" 500 120442

Comment: El error ante el fallo de conversión de `str` a `float` es `ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'cadena'`, si solo te imprime `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ` indica que está  **recibiendo una cadena vacía**, (`float('')`).  ¿Estás seguro que el error se produce en `coin.change = float(....`  cuando la línea anterior te imprime un `float` válido como `0.01`?

Comment: @FJSevilla Pues es lo que da a entender los print y el error... voy a actualizar con el error entero